# "prop" is undefined though it's being passed correctly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-props

I've been following VueJS official documentation on passing data to child components with props; though I'm not working with a string template. I'm aware about what happens when your prop is camel case; you should write it as kebab case.

Nevertheless, this is not the case since it's all lowercase and won't work.

I'm using nuxt and I've separated my work into files, which are:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Write your question" v-model="text">
    <select v-model="selectedField">
        <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="$emit('add-field')"
    v-bind:class="{ disabled: ($parent.count <= 1 && $parent.count == identifier) }">
    >{{identifier}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click="$emit('delete-field')">-</button>
</div>
```

Now for its JS file:

```
export default {
data () {
  return {
    options: [
        {
            id: 1,
            value: 1,
            text: "Radio"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            value: 2,
            text: "Rate"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            value: 3,
            text: "Text"
        }
    ],
    props: ['identifier'],
    selectedField: 1,
    text: "",
  }
  },
  }
```

Now, for my parent component:

```
<template>
<div class="offset-md-3" id="qz">
    <form-maker
        v-for="item in questions" :key="item._id"
        v-on:add-field="addField()"
        v-on:delete-field="deleteField(item._id)"
        v-bind:identifier="item._id" <<--What I want to set
        ref="child"
    ></form-maker>
<button @click="saveForm" class="btn btn-large btn-success">SAVE</button>

</div>
</template>
```

Finally:

```
var vm = null;

export default {
    layout: 'admin',
    components: {
        formMaker
    },
    data() {
        return {
            count: 1,
            questions: [{
                _id: 1//static
            }]
        }
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, to use the prop for some validations, nevertheless it throws the next error:

> Property or method "identifier" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where you go wrong. Props should not be in `data()`. See the code snippet below

```html
<script>
export default {
    props: ['identifier'],
    data() {
        return {
            options: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    value: 1,
                    text: "Radio"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    value: 2,
                    text: "Rate"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    value: 3,
                    text: "Text"
                }
            ],           
            selectedField: 1,
            text: "",
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Jeez, how could I overlook that... It's solved now, much apprecciated!

Comment: Glad I helped. Thanks too